# Not able to register my 64bit dll through nsis script ?

Tags: nsis, dllregistration

I have a 64bit dll which i'm able to register from command prompt with regsvr32. But the problem is when i try to register my dll through nsis script its not registered. I used **RegDLL** command in nsis script. Anyone knows what the problem may be?

Comment: The problem is almost certainly that it's a 32-bit process trying to load your 64-bit DLL. I don't have a clue how to fix it, though.

Comment: @Gabe running external regsrv32 is definitely one of options ;)

Comment: @Gabe 32-bit process u mean installer. if so how do i make a 64-bit nsis installer ?

Comment: @Eugene: I should say that I have no clue how to fix it in NSIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use [rundll32.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787) instead:

```
ExecWait '"$SYSDIR\rundll32.exe" $INSTDIR\mydll.dll DllRegisterServer'
```

rundll32.exe is smart enough to launch the 64bit version of itself if you run it with a 64bit dll

Comment: I think that it would better use regsvr32, it's the program that MS provides to register ActiveX DLL's and it also detects 32/64 bits DLL's (just use the /s parameter to omit messages). MS blogger Raymond Chen advises against using rundll32, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/01/04/10382242.aspx

Comment: @Bevan Collins Thank you, you saved my day! It turned out that your approach is the only way to register a 64 bit DLL out of a 32 bit installer.

Answer (score 3):

RegDLL is known to be problematic in anything but the simplest scenarios. Google `site:forums.winamp.com nsis` for examples.

To make sure that registration of your DLL, type library, BHO, etc occurs successfully, you should use `InstallLib`. It provides an option for x64 library installation (plus more!)

See http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixB.html#B.1 for more details about library installation with NSIS.

Answer (score 2):

ExitWait not found NSIS script. ExitWait instead ExecWait.

you cound use:

ExecWait '"$SYSDIR\rundll32.exe" $INSTDIR\mydll.dll DllRegisterSe